# trying to yarn build polkadot-js/apps and getting error

Tags: polkadot-js

I'm trying to clone and build this [branch (supersig-v1.0.0-ninja-2)](https://github.com/decentration/apps/tree/supersig-v1.0.0-ninja-2), but getting an issue on my mac, while on ubuntu it works fine.

`yarn build`:

error:

```
apps % yarn build:code
$ polkadot-dev-build-ts 
$ yarn polkadot-dev-clean-build
$ polkadot-dev-clean-build 
$ yarn build:extra

   3 not referenced in chains ::

         chainsDustyPNG, chainsMangataxPNG, chainsPicassoSVG 


  18 not referenced in nodes ::

         nodesAresPNG, nodesBeastSVG, nodesEaveSVG, nodesIdavollPNG, nodesIpseSVG, nodesKonomiPNG, nodesMoonrockPNG, nodesParamiJPEG, nodesPlasmPNG, nodesShellSVG, nodesSinglavenderSVG, nodesSubstrateCircleSVG, nodesSubstrateHexagonSVG, nodesSubstrateWhiteSVG, nodesUnitvPNG, nodesValiuPNG, nodesVaraSVG, nodesZenlinkSVG 

$ polkadot-dev-run-test --env node --require ./scripts/fixupModules.cjs --experimental-specifier-resolution=node packages/apps-config/src/api/typesBundle.spec.ts
$ /usr/local/bin/node --no-warnings --enable-source-maps --loader @polkadot/dev/node/ts --require @polkadot/dev/node/test/node --require ./scripts/fixupModules.cjs --experimental-specifier-resolution=node /Users/ramsey/new-apps/apps/node_modules/@polkadot/dev/scripts/polkadot-exec-node-test.mjs packages/apps-config/src/api/typesBundle.spec.ts
SyntaxError: The requested module 'node:test' does not provide an export named 'run'
    at ModuleJob._instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:123:21)
    at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:189:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:533:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:91:5)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:65:12)
Error: Command failed: yarn build:extra
    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:841:11)
    at Object.execSync (node:child_process:912:15)
    at execSync (file:///Users/ramsey/new-apps/apps/node_modules/@polkadot/dev/scripts/util.mjs:79:6)
    at main (file:///Users/ramsey/new-apps/apps/node_modules/@polkadot/dev/scripts/polkadot-dev-build-ts.mjs:946:5)
    at file:///Users/ramsey/new-apps/apps/node_modules/@polkadot/dev/scripts/polkadot-dev-build-ts.mjs:988:1
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:533:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:91:5) {
  status: 1,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  pid: 29518,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null
}
```

highlighted error:

```
SyntaxError: The requested module 'node:test' does not provide an export named 'run'
```

Answer (score 5):

So i was able to get your code built. I would ensure you are using the correct version of `node` as the error you are posting comes from node-js itself.

Ensure you are using version `18.15` or higher as declared in the `engine` field in the package.json.